# Show Cartodb Maps infowindow on hover programatically

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-js, infowindow, angularjs

How do i get to show the cartodb infowindow when one hovers over a point? I see that it is possible via the gui but how can one do it via code? what method should i call on the on('featureOver') event?

Comment: I have the same question. It is possible to catch 'click' and 'hover' events. But I miss the possiblity to control the popup of the info window in dependency of the data handed over to event callback.

Comment: Please do get back, when and if you solve this without hacks

Answer (score 1):

Use two layers. One containing only objects without info windows and the other for objects with info windows only. For the first disallow info windows, in the second allow them.